# When would I use browsers through selenium node vs remote selenium server?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

To hook up a browser instance to selenium grid, one would need to either use selenium node or remote selenium server. In what situation would it be appropriate to use one over the other? Is it bad practice to have remote selenium servers hook up directly to the grid? Currently I have desktop browser hooked up through nodes and only have my android/iOS instances directly communicating to the grid through the use flynnid (https://github.com/davehunt/flynnid), but it seems possible to delegate them to a node instead, but would there be any benefit?

Some Reference:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you got the right references.

Secondly the difference I see between Grid and the RemoteWebDriverServer is, that the Grid always provides a ready setup to start testing- with a central point of execution.

If you are not the one and only "Master of Test- Execution" in your company this may be a tremendous advantage for others if they can see which setups are available via

`http://host:port/grid/console`.

That's what I personally favour most about the whole thing